# does super only go one level above?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

if I have:

```
class Zero {
    int n = 0;

    void setN(int x) {
        n += x;
    }
}

class One extends Zero {
    int n = 1;

    void setN(int x) {
        n += x;
        super.setN(x);
    }

}

class Two extends One {
    int n = 2;

    void setN(int x) {
        n += x;
        super.setN(x);
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(super.n);
        // System.out.println(super.super.n);   error

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Two two = new Two();
        two.show();
        // >>>
        // 2
        // 1

        two.setN(1);
        two.show();
        // >>>
        // 3
        // 2
    }
}
```

**I re-edited it, with a method `setN` pass down from `Zero`. It worked, so does it mean that I can still 'change' the `n` in `Zero`, but I just won't see it?**

**It is also very interesting that even though `setN` is exactly the same in `One` and `Two`, I have to manually override it, if I delete `setN` in `Two`, this will behave differently. The `setN` won't change `n` in `Two`.**

It seems that `super` can only go one level above? Is there anyway to call `n` in zero?

But the other question is that if I intended to override `int n` in subclass, why is it allow me to visit `n` in parent at all?

Thanks,

Comment: No, you can't go "two up" with `super`.  As for why Java allows you to access `n` in the superclass, you'd have to ask those clever people who designed the language.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  So principally I should not be able to visit `n` even in `One`?

Comment: Fields can not be overriden. Field with the same name in a subclass hides field in parent class. You still can acccess parent class fields by casting object to parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Java unlike C++ which supports it using scope resolution.

You could have a method

```java
int getZeroN(){
    return n;
}
```

in your `Zero` and then call it using `System.out.println(super.getZeroN());` from `Two`

Answer (score 1):

You can, however do this in Two.main():

```
   Two two = new Two();
   Zero z = (Zero)two;
   System.out.println( Zero's n is " + z.n );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't go two levels up with `super`. It can be used also with arguments. as `super(argument1)` and it will call the constructor that accepts 1 parameter of the type of `argument1` (if exists).

Also it can be used to call methods from the parent. `super.method()`

for more information you can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)